# Javascript: arguments change with further apply processing

Tags: javascript

```
    function Foo(){

    }
    Foo.prototype={
        method1:function(o){
            console.log(o);
        }
        ,shorthand:function(){
            if(!arguments.length || typeof arguments[0]=='undefined') {
                arguments[0]={};
            }
            arguments[0].bar='test';
            return this.method1.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    }

    var instance=new Foo();
    instance.shorthand();

console.log(o); // returns undefined
```

After a while i figured out, that assigning arguments an array fixes this.

```
arguments=[{bar:'test'}];
```

I figured out, that arguments is not an array after all, or semi-array. Well it doesn't have push method.

Why is it doing so(i mean returns undefined)? It's been made for some purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have seen that `arguments` is not an array, but only "array-like". It is a normal object which has numerical keys and a `length` property:

[image: arguments object]

Your code

```
arguments[0]={};
arguments[0].bar='test';
```

**does** work in some way.

But because it is not an array, the `length` property is not updated. So although you added a property, `length` is still `0`:

[image: arguments length 0]

Now, I don't know the implementation of `apply` but I assume it uses the `length` property to iterate over all elements in the "array". If length is zero, it does not pass any arguments to the function, so `o` in this case is indeed `undefined`.

If you add

```
arguments.length = 1;
```

then it [works as you expected](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/PM5gZ/).

Assigning an array to `arguments` just overwrites the object and assigning elements to an array updates `length` as it is known.